# PHP latest Tweet

Tags: php, twitter

I've created a twitter class with a method that pulls in the latest tweet depending on the user specified...uses twitter .XML

```
class twitter {

// Set twitter basepath
public $basepath = 'http://twitter.com/statuses';

function tweet($username){   

    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($this->basepath.'/user_timeline/'. $username .'.xml?count=1', NULL, TRUE);
    $status = $xml->status->text;

    return '<b>' . $username . ' says: </b>' . $status;
}
```

}

this echo's out

```
XXXXX says: @XXXX Moving it up to 10am on Sunday - it's about a 1.5 hour drive.
```

How do I get php to link the "@" tag as a HTML link instead of just text??
Is there a way to look for the string "@" and replace the remaining word with a href?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using this one:

```
$status = preg_replace('#@(\w+)\b#', '<a href="http://twitter.com/$1">@$1</a>', $status);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PHP regex matching with this pattern:
 `@([A-Za-z0-9_]+)` to get all of the @USER tags.

From there, you can wrap the text in `<a href="USER">@USER</a>`.

(Should work:)

EXAMPLE:

```
<?php
preg_match_all("@([A-Za-z0-9_]+)",
    $tweet,
    $users, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

foreach($user in $users) {
    str_replace($user,
        "<a href='http://twitter.com/".substr($user, 1)."'>" . $user . "</a>",
        $tweet);
}
?>
```

Comment: An example would be most helpful Rurize

Comment: Added. Should work, haven't tested. The tweet is stored in `$tweet`